# Ошибка в NetBeand IDE 8.2

Tags: c++, netbeans, компилятор

Установил NetBeans, с самого начала была эта ошибка. Уже и MinGW переустанавливал, и пути все проверял, ничего не помогло. Ошибка абсолютно одинаковая, хоть 10 строк, хоть 200[image: Вот программа (Специально самая простая чтобы было понятно), а снизу ошибка, такая всегда]

Comment: Так а ошибка говорит об отсутствии make

Comment: А где его взять?

Comment: А где Вы брали mingw? Если на mingw.org, то make надо брать оттуда же. А если у Вас сборка, например, mingw-TDM или mingw-w64, то у них в комплекте уже все есть.